# How to facet on Sitecore Tags using ContentSearchManager

Tags: sitecore, sitecore7

I understand how to use the ContentSearchManager to search for items and how to facet on fields. But I can't quite figure out how to facet on the tags that I have created in Sitecore. The UI facets on them by default, but in the index using the ContentSearchManager. Does anyone have knowledge of it? Thank you

```csharp
FacetResults facets = new FacetResults();

facets = query.Where(x => x.Language.Equals(computedLanguage)
                          && (x.PageTitle.Contains(text)))
                         .FacetOn(facet => facet.tags).GetFacets();
```

Comment: I know this is just past a year old now, but since I am heavily involved in a Sitecore search project ATM, I wanted to add a link to their tag article for anyone who comes upon this looking for context: http://www.sitecore.net/Learn/Blogs/Technical-Blogs/Sitecore-7-Development-Team/Posts/2014/03/Content-Tagging-with-Sitecore-7.aspx

Answer (score 7):

I am not sure where you have the "tags" property defined since it is not a property that is defined in the default SearchResultItem class provided by Sitecore and you don't show the declaration of "query".  "Semantics" is actually the property you would want to use to access the GUIDs for the tags that are defined on your item.

There are two approaches to faceting on those Tags now.  You could just facet on the Semantics property to get the faceting based on GUID.  You would then look up the GUID in Sitecore to get the name of the Tag.

```csharp
FacetResults facets = new FacetResults();

facets = query.Where(x => x.Language.Equals(computedLanguage)
                      && (x.PageTitle.Contains(text)))
                     .FacetOn(facet => facet.Semantics).GetFacets();
```

The other approach would be to actually store the Tag Names in your Search Index.  This gives you the added benefit of allowing users to easily search by Tag name.

The computed field to store your Tags names in the index would look something like this:

```csharp
public class TagsFacet : IComputedIndexField
{
    public object ComputeFieldValue(IIndexable indexable)
    {
        var indexableItem = indexable as SitecoreIndexableItem;

        if (indexableItem == null)
        {
            return null;
        }

        if (indexableItem.Item.Fields["__Semantics"] == null) return null;

        MultilistField tags = indexableItem.Item.Fields["__Semantics"];

        var tagNames = tags.GetItems().Select(tag => tag.Name).ToList();

        return tagNames;
    }

    public string FieldName { get; set; }
    public string ReturnType { get; set; }
}
```

You will need to add in the computed field to your Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneDefaultIndexConfiguration.config (assuming you are using Lucene) in the raw:AddComputedIndexField section:

```xml
<field fieldName="tagsfacet">SitecoreBase72.TagsFacet,SitecoreBase72</field>
```

You will then need to extend the SearchResultItem class to add the new field name:

```csharp
public class CustomSearchModel : SearchResultItem
{
    [IndexField("tagsfacet")]
    public List<String> tagsFacet { get; set; } 

}
```

And finally you can facet on your tag fields (once you rebuild your index):

```csharp
var searchIndex = ContentSearchManager.GetIndex("sitecore_master_index");

using (var context = searchIndex.CreateSearchContext())
{
    var myTagFacets = new FacetResults();

    myTagFacets = context.GetQueryable<CustomSearchModel>()                        
                  .FacetOn(facet => facet.tagsFacet)
                  .GetFacets();

    foreach (var facetCategories in myTagFacets.Categories)
    {
        foreach (var facet in facetCategories.Values)
        {
            Log.Info(string.Format("Facet:{0} Results:{1}",facet.Name,facet.AggregateCount),this);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: I am able to facet on "tags" because I already extended the SearchResultItem to include my field "tags". And I linked the Tag field to to the semantics field.

          <fields hint="raw:AddCustomField">
            <field luceneName="__semantics" storageType="yes" indexType="tokenized" multivalued="true">tags</field>
          </fields>

Thank you for the info. So I am going to facet on Semantics like I have always faceted on other fields. But I am going to try your computed field values.

Comment: Is there any special way of retrieving the search results based on tag facets selected? or do we use the regular syntax for IQueryable on the queryable collection of SearchResultItem(s)?

Comment: @aceanindita When you select a value, you will use a .Where() query or PredicateBuilder if you have multiple selections or more complicated queries. query.Where(i => i["Tag"] == selectedValue);